# Is it only the first character of a const char * that is constant?

Tags: c

When declaring a constant string, is the entire string `read-only` or just the initial character?

```
const char* s = "hello";
```

Comment: The entire string (even without `const`), string literals are usually placed in read-only segments.

Comment: Moreover, C doesn't have strings... Just char arrays or pointers to char.

Comment: @ForceBru: everybody calls those things (C) strings.

Comment: why would you ever come up with the idea that it's only the first character that's `const`… *why?*

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, while Dennis Ritchie says they're char arrays and pointers in "The C programming language". Sure, _everyone_'s wiser :)

Comment: @ForceBru: you're right, now you've mentioned it, Plato haven't called them strings either. how silly of me.

Comment: @ForceBru you can call char arrays and pointers strings. Yes, they *are* char arrays and/or pointers. That doesn't mean that they can't be called strings.

Comment: @ForceBru they are referred to as "string literals" all over the Standard.

Comment: @ForceBru an example from the standard: "*A **character string literal** is a sequence of zero or more multibyte characters enclosed in double-quotes, as in "xyz". A UTF−8 string literal is the same, except prefixed by u8. A wide string literal is the same, except prefixed by the letter L, u, or U.*" (6.4.5, paragraph 3). C doesn't have a string type, for sure, but it most certainly has a standard-defined notion of what a string is.

Comment: @zubergu: not true. it makes the pointed thing immutable if accessed through the pointer. yes, string literals are immutable, but omitting `const` would be a programmer error.

Comment: @zubergu: Not true, the `const` makes an attempt to modify the string a compile-time error instead of waiting to segfault at run-time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"hello"
```

is a string literal. The string literal object is of a `char` array type and is specified as unmodifiable by C. It means that trying to modify it invokes undefined behavior.

```
 const char* s = "hello";
```

Now with the declaration above `s` is a pointer to the string literal object `"hello"`. It points to the first character of the string. By qualifying it as `const` you make a promise to the compiler that you won't use `s` pointer to modify what it is pointing to.

Any pointer arithmetic on `s` by adding it an integer value also yields a `const char *`. For example `s + 1` is also a `const char *` and so you cannot use `s + 1` to modify what it points to, that is for example `s[1] = 0` (or equivalent `*(s + 1) = 0`) is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Relative to this definition

```
const char* s = "hello";
```

then the pointer defined such a way that it points to an object of type const char. So the object pointed by the pointer and in this case it is the first character of the string literal may not be changed.

Take into account that you can reassign the pointer. For example

```
const char* s = "hello";

//...
char c = 'A';
s = &c;
```

Though the object with name c is not a constant object itself nevertheless it is pointed to by pointer s with qualifier const and it is supposed that it points to const data and you may not use this pointer to change the object.

On the other hand though string literals themselves in C have types of (non-const) character arrays you may not change them even if you will declare the pointer like this

```
char* s = "hello";
```

Any attempt to modify a string literal results in undefined behaviour. Implementations are allowed to place string literals in read-only memory.